# How to unhide part?

Tags: modeling

[image][image]I was trying to do some work on a part in blender, I had most everything else hidden. I clicked on some other part and the one I was working on disappeared. I can't find it on any layer, alt-h isn't doing anything. How can I get the part back? **The part that's missing is only showing a handful of faces, the rest of it won't show.**

[image]

---

Well apparently it was some bug in blender, i left the file open for a while in the background, i went to it again, it reloaded and now it's working fine.

Comment: It will be helpful to those wanting to try to help you if upload your ~.blend file to a hosting site and edit your question to include a link to the file. If you don't have a site you prefer, you can use the Blend-exchange site hosted by [GiantCowFilms](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If some *but not all* geometry from an object is missing, and you are *not* in edit mode, then I would consider checking that the object in question doesn't have any active modifiers, like a boolean.

If you are trying to perform a boolean operation with objects that are non-manifold, the normals are messed up, or the object is just modeled poorly, then a boolean will make some of the faces disappear.